# Animating metaballs

Tags: animation

I've tried to find an answer here on this subject, but no luck. So, bare with me:

How do I animate metaballs? I know it must be a really basic question, and from what I gather you have to use some node based animation for this

Comment: You can keyframe metaballs, what sort of animation are you trying and what difficulty have you met?

Comment: I can't animate them, as they all end up in the same "object" (I can only move them around in Edit mode). I'd like them to animate like splitting from and connecting to each other like some classic alien blobs. :)

Comment: Metaballs can be animated at Object level.. they will interact so long as they belong to the same [family](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/metas/editing.html#object-families), which is defined by naming-convention.

Comment: Ah, sorry. Silly me, I must've copied the metaballs in Edit mode (embarrassing).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to seperate metaballs as "2 objects", just rename the second metaball to another name. Then it works.